# PCB Layout validation

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

[image: bottom]
[image: top]

I'd like to know if the pcb layout is ok for the 2 op amps that i use.I'm interested in grounding and if the op-amps have proper layout(not too long loops or poor ground planes).
[source files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x9bCOsrTZ3Z0eRg_sHyRzvrqRodrMEYd/view?usp=sharing)
The files are all in the zip archive.
You can use the easyEDA to view the gerbers or EAGLE.I used Eagle 9.3.2.

Comment: In order to allow everybody to comment on the layout, please include images of the PCB.

Comment: Shopping recommendation questions are off topic, your welcome to ask these questions in the chat. I think you could expand your original question and write a better question, be specific

Comment: All the CAD data is in the zip file.I only need a final validation before sending for production(for me ,hobby) regarding grounding and other noise problems that arise from pcb layout.

Comment: What switching power supplies do you use? If any, how is their VDD noise filtered? What about electric-field interferers? what about MCUs on the same PCB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your power supply de-coupling is still very bad. The overall bypass is still closed with 4 vias in-series (RED marked by me):

[image]
[image]

The [manufacturer](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa113/sbaa113.pdf) strongly suggests "star connection" for power bypass, and not using any ground planes around:

[image]

If you have the ground plane, the bypass traces should be connected to the plane at only ONE point (making it as a "star"). And (+) and (-) pads should have voids in the ground plane, to reduce parasitic capacitance to ground that might change feedback transfer function and cause overall instability.